# Remote Desktop Printing TCP/IP

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2016, network-printer

I have a Windows Server 2016 x64 Application server.
I have tested all kinds of printer and it's working fine. 
But when clients are trying to print from remote session,
who have installed Standard TCP/IP port printers, they get error while printing from remote desktop.
I have checked printer driver and that's fine. what could be the creating issue?
is it in my end or in my client's end?

I have tested on:

- Brother 5450DN(TCP/IP) printer
- Adobe PDF
- All other shared printers
- all other network shared printers

The client have

- Brother MFC 8890DW (TCP/PC) printer shared from other computer.

Hope for kindly co-operation.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @EsaJokinen "Could not start printer. Please check your printer configuration." from -Libre Document, and "The document could not be printed" from -Adobe acrobat reader. But clients can direct print from local pc.

Comment: The problem is based in real case scenario. Rather than just down voting, it would help if you asked what confused you had in my question. or you can try suggesting answer to the question in the way you understood my issue.

Comment: Can the server print on the client ip's? Not sure how that works , but is the traffic routed through the client?

Comment: @TomTom I am not sure yet. but, client can print pdf on their own computer from there.

Comment: That would be an obvious issue, though - direct ip, and the server can not reach the printer. I would check this.

Comment: @TomTom  i am not sure but TSPrint (https://www.terminalworks.com/remote-desktop-printing) work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked a lot with printing issues and RDP earlier. It might be you are fooled by the fact its using TCP ports on the printers.

Make sure the print spooler service in running when you are trying to print, and make sure its running after you've tried. Many drivers are a huge piece of crap and should never be allowed to run in terminal server environments. Typically problem is they create some dialog in session 0 on the server and this is not allowed (any more) in terminal server environments and this cause the driver to crash, which might result in the print spooler service to crash and then you get errors like about.

Comment: I have to check print spooler at my end or in my client's end? can you please provide me reference URLs?

Comment: The print spooler is a windows NT service running on both clients and servers. I would start looking at the server side.